# modifie style base on state with styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, components, state

I have a function component as such

```
const Navbar = ({setNav, nav}) => {
  const [justify, setJustify] = useState('space-around')
  //get localStorage
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));


  //change state of nav to display user details
  if(user){
    setNav(true)
  }
  console.log(nav)



  return (
    <Nav>
      <Img src={logo} alt='groupomania' />
      {nav  ? <UserDetail setNav={setNav}/> : ''}
    </Nav>
  );
};
```

I would like to modify the `justify-content` styling based on the state

I have tried the following without success

```
const Nav = styled.nav`
  position: sticky;
  background: #eeeeee;
  min-height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: ${nav  ? 'space-between' : 'space-around'};
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  padding: 1rem 10rem;
  top: 0px;
`
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you just directly put that clause inline.

```js
<Nav style={{ 'justify-content': nav ? 'space-between' : 'space-around' }}>
  ... ...
</Nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bubai for your reference check what I found too

Answer (score 0):

While the answer of Bubai would work. However, I am not fond of inline styling.

After some trying around the more suitable solution would be:

```
 <Nav>
   <Img src={logo} alt='groupomania' />
   {nav  ? <UserDetail setNav={setNav} nav={nav} /> : ''}
</Nav>
```

I have added the `nav={nav}` prop to the component.
Then I can do the following:

```
const Nav = styled.nav`
  position: sticky;
  background: #eeeeee;
  min-height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: ${props => props.nav  ? 'space-between' : 'space-around'};
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  padding: 1rem 10rem;
  top: 0px;
`
```

This link was very helpful https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced